# Can you change an object while it is being serialized and does that affect the serialization result?

Tags: c#, serialization

Is it possible, that changes are made to an object, that is currently serialized?
If yes, does this break the serialization?
For example:
If I want to realize autosaves in a game and serialize the user character while the player keeps doing stuff and changes objects, that are to be serialized (for example the player object itself), will that
a) be possible
b) change the byte stream "on the fly" and result in corrupted data?

Comment: on the fly autosaves in a game are so that all the data that gets needs to be saved gets copyed first, should also be done in sync(no other thread should access it), and then that gets saved to a file async

Comment: @Vajura So, this will result in a short "lag" since the user cannot input changes while the copy is being created?

Comment: yes but if you data structure is not bad this "lag" should be 10ms or less, essentialy nothing. Thats why i said you need to copy it first and then save it to disk (since saving to disk could take longer) and the saving to disk is done async then which will cause no lag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather a problem with concurrency, not so much about serialisation.

If you have one thread changing the object while another thread is reading from it, the result will be corrupted data. You need to synchronise the access to the object so that reading and changing it at the same time is not possible.

Comment: Could I avoid that by creating a temporary deep copy?

Comment: @Markai: No, then you need to synchronise that instead so that you don't get a corrupted copy. That can however be useful to minimise the lock time if the synchronising takes a long time.

Comment: Oops, the last sentence should of course be: "That can however be useful to minimise the lock time if the serialisation takes a long time."